# I'm facing this error when i add platfrom in cordova application

Tags: cordova

Using cordova-fetch for cordova-android@~7.1.1

> Failed to fetch platform cordova-android@~7.1.1
>   Probably this is either a connection problem, or platform spec is incorrect.
>   Check your connection and platform name/version/URL.
>
> Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code ENOENT

Comment: Could you check your version with `cordova --version`

Comment: $ cordova --version
8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same headline error, at the end of the dump it pointed to a complete log file, the error output ended...

```
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\zzzzz\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-10-25T13_26_17_514Z-debug.log
```

in the log the error was in it trying to rename a folder... I had a file open in my desktop editor(duh !). Line 1020 of the log...

```
311 verbose stack Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\Users\zzzzz\source\repos\myApp\node_modules\cordova-android' -> 'C:\Users\zzzzz\source\repos\myApp\node_modules\.cordova-android.DELETE'
```

Closed the editor, reran the install it went fine!